# KOTLIN - Value passed between Fragments is null

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and recently have problem with retrieving value from Fragment.

FragmentTwo():

```
class FragmentTwo(): Fragment {
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val adapter = ListAdapter(requireContext(), myValueList, totalValueTV)
        val listView = id_ListView
        listView.adapter = adapter
        //***SOME CODE***
}


private class ListAdapter(context: Context, val myValueList: ArrayList<Value>, totalValueTV: TextView) :
    BaseAdapter() {

        //***SOME CODE***

        override fun notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged()

        val valueSum = CalculatorActivity().Sum(myValueList)
        totalValueTV.text = "TOTAL: $valueSum" // everything is working nice till here

       //****** now i am trying to save this "valueSum" to FragmentOne arguments
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putInt("sum1",valueSum)
        val fragmentOne = FragmentOne()
        fragmentOne.arguments=bundle
    }
}
```

FragmentOne()

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

// here i am trying to get this valueSum from arguments
   var sum = arguments?.getInt("sum1")
   id_mainTV.text = "My sum is: $sum"
}
```

**EDIT1:**
I am using NavigationDrawer in MainActivity. And only here is fragment transaction.

MainActivity():

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

//override fun onCreate here...

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_home -> {
                fragmentOne = FragmentOne()
                supportFragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.id_home_screen, fragmentOne)
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                    .commit()
            }
            R.id.nav_food -> {
                fragmentTwo = FragmentTwo()
                supportFragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.id_home_screen, fragmentTwo)
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                    .commit()
            }
         }
         drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
         return true
}
```

So, after i change my ListView from FragmentTwo, i want to pass my `valueSum` to FragmentOne.
Now, what i get in FragmentOne() is `$sum` as null.
I checked also that `FragmentOne().arguments == null`

I am new to Kotlin so thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: could you attach code with the transaction to `FragmentOne`?

Comment: Might I suggest using a `ViewModel` for communications between `Fragment`s? See https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel "share data between Fragments"

Comment: Ok Joozd, i will try with this ViewModel. Thank you for link!
@AndreiTanana i updated post with MainActivity code.